# GIT - Should I ignore Makefile, and other files generating by IDE?

Tags: git

I am working with QTCreator, and I wonder is it good habit to track files which probably everyone could generate by yourselfs (by IDE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add them to version control. In general, don't add any files created while building (even if it's just some intermediate IDE step). Otherwise every time you build your project you'll create local changes. Also the build files could contain local paths that aren't valid for others. Perfect example for this would be cross platform development on (e.g.) Windows and Unix. The makefiles will definitely be different in some way, even if both platforms use GCC.

Add makefiles only if they're used to build the project and they aren't created on the fly while working/building based on other files (project files for example; add those instead then). Only add the minimal set of files required to build and run the project (excluding sharred library files, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

If it's wizard-style generated (i.e. you clicked through some interface, and are then expected/allowed to adjust the files to your needs), you should definitely track them.

If they are actually build results (i.e. generated over and over again, on every copy where the build process is run), you shouldn't commit them.

In the case of a Makefile: yes, this should probably go into revision control.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule I'd say no, these property files for the IDE are likely to have environment specific paths/variables involved it's best to keep your source separated from your project files, this way the source files can be pulled into a different IDE and used as well (assuming you're able to configure the IDE to have the appropriate paths).  If it is well known your whole team and all teams in the future will use IDE X then I think it's okay but still not a great idea.  Maven or similar build tools help avoid this situation by allowing you to commit just your source and a pom.xml file which describes the compilation of the project (sort of like an Ant file) this way it can be built by anyone with maven from the command line, furthermore plugins provide the ability to generate the IDE specific files for users (for example I use the flexmojos:flexbuilder plugin at work or eclipse:eclipse to generate the project files for flexbuilder or eclipse).  This depends a fair amount on your work flow, team size, disparity of said teams IDEs among other factors.